# C: Passing any function to a function

Tags: c, function, pointers, function-pointers, generic-programming

I would like to know how I would go about passing any function to a function, as in a generic function pointer that can take any function whatsoever, The goal of this is to make a destructor system, so basically storing the function and calling it with it's arguments also stored later down the line,

Something like:

```
Defer(SDL_DestroyWindow, Window);
```

I already handled the arguments, but I don't know how to manage the function pointer part of this, Thank you!

Edit: I added more info ...

```
typedef struct {
  void** args;
} IM_Defer_Resource;
/* Defer & Whatnot */

IM_Stack* IM_Defer_Stack;

void IM_Defer_Init() {
  IM_Defer_Stack = IM_Stack_Init();
}


void IM_Defer(/* What to put here? */) {

}

void IM_Defer_All() {
  while(IM_Defer_Stack->size) {
    IM_Defer_Resource* resource = IM_Stack_Pop(IM_Defer_Stack);
    if(!resource) continue;
    /* What to do */
  }
}
```

I don't have the actual functions of defer, but I did copy every argument into the stack and can pop them successfully, I don't know how to implement the variadic function calling though

Edit2:
After receiving some input: I think this would be more feasible:
Defer(SDL_DestroyWindow, "SDL_Window*", window);
I am brainstorming how this would be possible, but I would appreciate some input

Edit3:

```
/* Defer & Whatnot */
typedef struct {
  char** types;
  void** args;
  int count;
} IM_Defer_Resource;


IM_Stack* IM_Defer_Stack;

void IM_Defer_Init() {
  IM_Defer_Stack = IM_Stack_Init(IM_Get_Stack_Type(IM_Defer_Resource));
}

void IM_Defer_Internal(void* var, int n, ...) {
  char* type;
  void* arg;

  va_list args;
  va_start(args, n);

  IM_Defer_Resource resource;
  int count = n / 2;
  resource->types = calloc(count, sizeof(char*));
  resource->args = calloc(count, sizeof(void*));
  resource->count = count;

  for(count > 0; n -= 1) {
    type = va_arg(args, char*);
    resource->types[count-1] = type;
    arg = va_arg(args, void*);
    resource->args[count-1] = arg;
  }

  IM_Stack_Push(IM_Defer_Stack, &resource);
}

void IM_Defer_All() {
  while(IM_Defer_Stack->size) {
    IM_Defer_Resource* resource = IM_Stack_Pop(IM_Defer_Stack);
    if(!resource) continue;
    /* I have a char* and a void* to the resource, Now what? */
    free(resource->types);
    free(resource->args);
  }
}
```

This is what I came up with, but I am wondering how I can conver that char* into a type...

Comment: You may be able to do something with variadic-macro tricks, although I'm rusty on that ;)

Comment: Any function pointer of one type can be cast to a function pointer of another type.  So using `foo(int (*f)()) { ... }` is sufficient for passing a function pointer (the _value_).  The trick is how to pass the _type_.  Code use a `union` and an enumerated value for a finite list of types - but _any_ type? --> recommend to narrow the goal.

Comment: @chux - The problem is then how to pass a variable number of arguments to a (non-variadic) function pointer.

Comment: "I already handled the arguments" --> posting your code that does this would add clarity to your goal.

Comment: @chux, I am basically just adding every argument to a void** pointer and keeping track of then number of arguments

Comment: Back to comment. it takes too long to describe the possible solution. When declaring a variadic function the undeclared parameters are subject to the `default argument promotions`. This means that you can find the passed arguments different from that intended by the function, that will eventually lead to exceptions. What you want to do is feasible, but really very complex. You must use descriptors similar to those used in `printf` format string to reconvert parameters, on receiving side, back to the form required by the function you want to call.

Comment: @Frankie_C So is there no generic way of doing this? I am willing to do this with a finite number of predefined types, that is okay with me :\, As long as they can be defined via code and not hardcoded

Comment: There could be, as I said, but is very very complex. If you have a C11 capable compiler you can also try to use the `_Generic` for generic selection crafting a group of wrapping functions containing a set of parameters that can fit any type of functions you want to use, then locally call the function using only appropriate parameters. Consider that this is one of the reason that makes peoples choice C++...

Comment: @Frankie_C  So how does printf handle automatic undeclared argument promotion?  You can pass it any size integer as long as the format string matches, can't you?

Comment: `printf` knows well what to expect. It is a variadic function that knows that its arguments got `default promotions` and can handle each one following the `format string`. Even using `printf` if you declare `"%d"` and then pass a float you will get an UB.

Comment: @Frankie_C I updated the question to be more feasible

Answer (score 0):

As I said in comment a big problem is that when declaring a variadic function the undeclared parameters are subject to the `default argument promotions`. This means that you can find the passed arguments different from that intended by the function, that will eventually lead to exceptions. What you want to do is feasible, but really very complex.

One solution, but limited because requires a lot of coding, could be:

```
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef enum { fn1, fn2, fn3, /*....*/} e_fn;

void multi_fun(e_fn fn, ...)
{
    va_list ap;
    int j;

    va_start(ap, fn); /* Requires the last fixed parameter (to get the address) */

    switch(fn)
    {
        case fn1:
        {
            //suppose prototype for fn1 to be void fn1_fn(int, float, struct  mystruct *);
            int   this_int   = va_arg(ap, int);
            float this_float = va_arg(ap, float);
            struct  mystruct *this_struct = va_arg(ap, struct  mystruct *);
            fn1_fn(this_int, this_float, this_struct);
            break;
        }

        case fn2:
        {
            ...
        }
    }
    va_end(ap);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [Fake Function Framework (fff)](https://github.com/meekrosoft/fff) on GitHub. They've done this using macros for caching mock functions. MIT Licensed. However, just like @Frankie_C said, this requires a LOT of code. The header file that defines all of the macros is around 6K LOC. And functions are still limited to 20 arguments.